# Can you use ssh2_scp_recv in php to get a remote directory?

Tags: php, scp, libssh2

I am trying to use

```
ssh2_scp_recv($connection, '/remote/directory', '/local/directory');
```

to get a remote directory, but I am getting the error:

```
Warning: ssh2_scp_recv(): Unable to receive remote file in /some-php-file.php on line 2.
```

It works if I use ssh2_scp_recv to get a single file.

Is this function supposed to work on directories?  It wasn't clear from reading the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `ssh2_scp_recv` to get a directory. You can, however, use scandir using `ssh2.sftp://` wrapper.

http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.ssh2.php

[Check this gist for an example](https://gist.github.com/danielbwa/6993444) credit for code to the gist owner danielbwa